# Matching by 3 values in R for case-control studies

Tags: r, matching

Im trying to conduct a study, not sure though if possible or not. However, I have a question regarding to this study, and hope to be useful for others as well.

I have a dataset like this

```
id   age    gender    v1      v2        v3     event
1    30     0         2.3     3.7       NA     1
2    31     0         1.3     4.3       4.1    0
3    40     1         3.1     NA        NA     1
4    41     1         2.3     2.7       NA     0
5    42     1         2.6     3.2       NA     0
6    53     1         2.5     2.4       NA     0
```

First approach, if is a case (event==1) then want to find a control (event==0) and to match them by age, gender. Than, as second approach, based on missing measures (v2, v3) of cases delete the measures (v2, v3) of controls.

Desired dataset should be like this:

```
id   age    gender    v1      v2        v3    event
1    30     0         2.3     3.7       NA    1
2    31     0         1.3     4.3       NA    0
3    40     1         3.1     NA        NA    1
4    41     1         2.3     NA        NA    0
5    42     1         2.6     NA        NA    0
```

I hope this is clear to everyone and might be useful for others.

Comment: It is not very clear.

Comment: updated to make it clear. Thanks for message.

Comment: I didn't understand how the `v3` columns all changed to `NA` and also for `v2`.  Also, matching by `Age` means is there any cutoff limits?

Comment: @akrun about gender was my typo mistake, fixed now and added one more row to make the question more clear. I changed to NA because the id3 which is an event doesn't have the measure v2. So the condition is created based on the cases (event=1). Let me know if is still no clear. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to set to NA the last not-NA element of the row when `event==0`?

Comment: @nicola, no we need first to match cases `event==1` with controls `event==0` based on age and gender, than for selected controls we need to delete the measures (v2, v3) if the cases has measures (v2, v3) NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
df$ageGrp <- cut(df$age, breaks=c(29,39,49,59), labels=c(30,40,50))
indx <-  with(df, !!ave(event, ageGrp, gender, 
                    FUN=function(x) any(!x) & any(!!x)))

 df1 <- df[indx,]

 fun1 <- function(x) {if(any(is.na(x))) rep(NA_real_, length(x)) else x}

 nm1 <- paste0("v", 1:3)
 res <- setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, fun1),by=list(gender, ageGrp), 
         .SDcols=nm1][,c("id", "age", "event"):= list(df1$id, df1$age, 
                          df1$event)][,ageGrp:=NULL]
 res

 #   gender  v1  v2 v3 id age event
 #1:      0 2.3 3.7 NA  1  30     1
 #2:      0 1.3 4.3 NA  2  31     0
 #3:      1 3.1  NA NA  3  40     1
 #4:      1 2.3  NA NA  4  41     0
 #5:      1 2.6  NA NA  5  42     0
```

Or you could use `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)

 df %>% 
    group_by(gender, ageGrp) %>%
    filter(any(event==1)&any(event==0)) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(fun1), starts_with("v")) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-ageGrp)

  #  id age gender  v1  v2 v3 event
  #1  1  30      0 2.3 3.7 NA     1
  #2  2  31      0 1.3 4.3 NA     0
  #3  3  40      1 3.1  NA NA     1
  #4  4  41      1 2.3  NA NA     0
  #5  5  42      1 2.6  NA NA     0
```

#### Update

If `NA` is replaced by `25` and want to fill `25` for the group if the event has it.

```
  df$v2[is.na(df$v2)] <- 25 #change the NAs to 25 in the dataset for testing
  df$v3[is.na(df$v3)] <- 25

  fun2 <- function(x) {if(any(x==25)) rep(25,length(x)) else x}

     df %>% 
         group_by(gender, ageGrp) %>%
         filter(any(event==1)&any(event==0)) %>%
         mutate_each(funs(fun2), starts_with("v")) %>%
         ungroup() %>%
         select(-ageGrp)
     #Source: local data frame [5 x 7]

     #   id age gender  v1   v2 v3 event
     #1  1  30      0 2.3  3.7 25     1
     #2  2  31      0 1.3  4.3 25     0
     #3  3  40      1 3.1 25.0 25     1
     #4  4  41      1 2.3 25.0 25     0
     #5  5  42      1 2.6 25.0 25     0
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(id = 1:6, age = c(30L, 31L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 53L
 ), gender = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), v1 = c(2.3, 1.3, 3.1, 
 2.3, 2.6, 2.5), v2 = c(3.7, 4.3, NA, 2.7, 3.2, 2.4), v3 = c(NA, 
4.1, NA, NA, NA, NA), event = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("id", 
"age", "gender", "v1", "v2", "v3", "event"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @akrun I'd like to share an idea I had last night. For grouping, I did the following `mutate(group = gsub("[0-9]$", "", age))`. If all ages are double-digit, this may be one way to create age group.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks for the idea.  Or you could use `substr(age, 1,1)` (might be a bit faster).  I was thinking that there might be cases <10.

Comment: @akrun I see. It is always better to prepare for all possibilities. I just put your `fun1` in `mutate` like this. `mutate_each(funs({if(any(is.na(.))) rep(NA_real_, length(.)) else .}), starts_with("v"))`. I have not written something like this in `funs` yet. This was good learning experience. I already upvoted. I wish I could vote one more time for this `funs` part.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks for the comments and voting.  I think if the age group 1-10 is included, `gsub` may be better than `substr` because  `gsub("[0-9]$", "", c(1,2, 3, 4, 11,25))#[1] ""  ""  ""  ""  "1" "2"` while `substr(c(1,2, 3, 4, 11,25), 1,1)#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "1" "2"`.  Still, the `""` should be converted to some value for the grouping purpose.  Yes, it is the correct syntax for the funs part.  I used `fun1` because I can use it for both the solutions.

Comment: @akrun Ah I see.That is a good point. Thanks for the explanation. This would be a quick way to group observations related to age. One note for today.

Comment: @arkun what about if instead of `NA` to be an unique number like `25`, how we should approach? Thank you. (ps. I had this question at beginning but i didn't want to make it more complicated)

Comment: @klo I didn't understand it correctly.  Could you show it in the post and the expected result.  Better would be to start a new question and post it so that others also look into it.

Comment: @akrun what you did is that if `event==1` (etc) you replaced the measures (v1,v2,v3) of `event==0` with `NA` (based on measures of event==1). Now because of other reasons instead of `NA` is a number `25` how we can approach. I don't think its needed to open another question because this is very specific case which wont help anyone. The code you did its perfect for many other users.

Comment: @klo if it is 25, then do you want to have 25 for all the others in the group or just NAs.  Also, in that case, if there is `NA` in the group, what would you want to do?

Comment: @akrun wont be any NA in those variables (v1,v2,v3) but a number 25. Yes I want to have only 25 in others (event==0). Thank you.

Comment: @akrun great thank you again for your generous help.

Comment: @akrun when i test this code (with fun1) in big (3000+) database I get lot of NA? maybe its explained by age variability? However, tried different groups and get different NA.

Comment: @klo Here the condition I used is `is.na(x)`.  So, if there is any NA in that particular group for that column, the column for that group will be all NAs.

Comment: @akrun, it works well when I test in small database, but when I add to big one than get all NA for other (v2,v3,v4,v5) measurements.

Comment: @klo Please check your database for anything unusual.  `dplyr` and `data.table` based methods can be applied to large datasets without much problems.

Comment: @akrun, thanks i will do so, but i think the issue comes from matching. In big database which are more homogenize in age and gender than something goes wrong.

Comment: @klo Without viewing the data, it is difficult to say what might be the problem.